# Add LinkLables programmatically and show Messagebox on click event

Tags: vb.net

I am adding few LinkLabels dynamically during runtime. I have the IDs of all link labels added to the form. How can I show an error message when a particular linklabel is clicked?

For exmaple. Consider 5 Link labels as show below

- Report 1
- Report 2
- Report 3
- Report 4
- Report 5

When LinkLable "Report 1" is clicked. I have to show a Message box which says "Report 1"

Note: I don't know how many link labels will be generated during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
Private Sub frm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

  Dim lnk As LinkLabel
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 1 To 5
     lnk = New LinkLabel
     lnk.Text = "Report " & i.ToString
     lnk.Location = New Drawing.Point(10, 25 * i)
     lnk.Parent = Me
     AddHandler lnk.LinkClicked, AddressOf lnk_LinkClicked
  Next

End Sub

Private Sub lnk_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs)

  Dim lnk As LinkLabel = CType(sender, LinkLabel)

  MessageBox.Show(lnk.Text)

End Sub
```